# pure css on hover text change

Tags: html, css, hover, onhover

I have three `div`s when hovered changes the text right below them (This is Text A, This is Text B, This is Text C). The default active text is Text B.

**I want to the color of `div.b` to change when I hover over `div.c`**

I have this working for the hover over `div.a:hover`

---

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLsh/)**

---

HTML

```
<div class="onHoverText">
<div class="a">Text A</div>
<div class="b">Text B</div>
<div class="c">Text C</div>
<div class="outputBox">
    <span>This is Text B</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.onHoverText {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.a, .b, .c {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3%;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.b {
    color: #FF0004;
    border-right: thin dashed #3A3A3A;
    border-left: thin dashed #3A3A3A;
    padding: 0 2%;
}
.a:hover, .c:hover {
    color: #FF0004;
}
.outputBox {
    font-size: 36px;
}
div.a:hover ~ div.outputBox span, div.c:hover ~ div.outputBox span {
    display: none;
}
div.a:hover ~ div.outputBox:after {
    content:' This is Text A';
}
div.c:hover ~ div.outputBox:after {
    content:' This is Text C';
}
div.a:hover ~ div.b:not(.active), div.c:hover ~ div.b:not(.active) {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Where do you think you "declared it's properties" ?

Comment: So, are you trying to get `.b` to not be red when you hover over `.c`?

Comment: I understood he's trying to get `.b` not to be red when you hover `.b`

Comment: If so, that's easy. Just add `.b:hover` to the last selector set

Comment: The problem is that `div.c:hover ~ div.b:not(.active)` will not work because `.c` is after `.b` in the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am doing little trick to get closer to your requirement. I have added the following two new styles. Check the fiddle.

```
.onHoverText:hover .b{color:#000;}
.b:hover{color:#FF0004 !important}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLsh/16/)

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason this isn't working is because the adjacent selector in CSS will only target elements after the target element:

> The general sibling combinator selector is very similar to the adjacent sibling combinator selector we just looked at. The difference is that that the element being selected doesn't need immediately succeed the first element, but can appear anywhere **after it**.

Source [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

[There is no previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector) in CSS.

You should use javascript as a workaround if you do not have the choice (here with jQuery) :

```
$('.a, .c').hover(function(){
    $('.b').toggleClass('disabled');
});
```

With a simple css class :

```
.b.disabled {
    color: #000;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dvLsh/15/)